# HTML onclick append textbox value to link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox with id main_category_lan1 as below.

```
<input type="text" name="main_category_lan1" id="main_category_lan1" Value="Hello">
```

And I have a link in the same page as below.

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popup('http://translate.google.com/#en/ta/'+document.getElementById('main_category_lan1').value"> Translator </a>
```

I want to append the textbox value to the "Onclick link" while clicking the link...

Expected output onclick is ,

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popup('http://translate.google.com/#en/ta/Hello').value"> Translator </a>
```

Comment: Based on what I see you want that your user enter the text in your input and then on click you pass the words to translate to google with GET and then you want to show the result of that translation on your same textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the closing parenthesis in your onclick attribute. Also, did you mean to use window.open() instead of popup()? This works:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://translate.google.com/#en/ta/'+document.getElementById('main_category_lan1').value)"> Translator </a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AXWr8/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function openLink() {
    window.open('http://translate.google.com/#en/ta/' +
      document.getElementById('main_category_lan1').value);
}

<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="openLink()">Translator</a>
```